# Immediately execute dynamically loaded JS script

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-script-loading

at the top of the head of my document I dynamically load a script:

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "mydomain.com/main.js");
var head = document.head;
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
</script>
```

Content of main.js:

```
console.log('test');
```

However, the page loads fully before it outputs `test`. In the network panel I can also see all the images loading before finally the script executes.

How can I make the script load and execute directly after it was inserted into the document?

Comment: Hi, my question is about a dynamically inserted script tag, the question you posted deals with regular script tags.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you *actually* trying to do here? This is a *very* uncommon scenario...

Comment: I am trying to load an external js file depending on the domain.
Eg:
domain1.com --> main1.js
domain2.com --> main2.js
However I need the code to execute as soon as possible, not after rendering.

Comment: This is most likely the problem: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async, dynamically inserted scripts are async by default. However, even if I set `script.async = false;`, the page will still render before the console output appears.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution myself. [Dynamically inserted scripts are treated as async by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async). Setting it to `async=false` fixed it:

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "mydomain.com/main.js");
script.setAttribute("async", "false");
var head = document.head;
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

move this `script` tag to the head of the html. then it should assure you that the script executes before any body is rendered. Also you could add this script to the start of the `body` tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It already is at the top of the head. However, it still consoles only after the full page is rendered.